# Setting Fuzziness to Auto for MatchQuery

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the fuzziness option for my MatchQuery, however I want to set the Fuzziness value to auto. Is there any way to do this?

Also, for the completion suggester you can set it to be unicode aware, is there any way to do this for my MatchQuery?

This is how I create the request:

```
 var request = new SearchRequest<object>
        {
            Types = types,
            Size = 5,
            Query = new QueryContainer(new MatchQuery
            {
                Field = new PropertyPathMarker { Name = "ProductName.autocomplete" },
                Query = q,
                Fuzziness = 2.0

            }),
            Fields = new[]
            {
                new PropertyPathMarker{Name = "ProductName"}
            }
        };
        return _client.Search<object>(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly at the moment you cant everywhere, we have a specialised interface that can represent all  fuzziness states but not all places taking a fuzziness parameter use it.

We received a pull request for this that we merged into our `2.0` branch since its a breaking change:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/pull/941

We have no ETA on a 2.0 release as of yet though.

Comment: is 2.0 stable indeed? I see that there are many issues with it. I wish that we can have solution for this on 1.7

Comment: 2.0 is stable yeah, although we did iron out several kinks in patch releases and a couple more will more will for sure follow. We are releasing updates to 2.0 at a much faster rate then we did for 1.x